# javascript ошибку в синтаксисе

Tags: javascript

Хочу, чтобы программа сравнила два элемента двумерного массива с ответом пользователя.

```js
var nstroypolverh = parseInt(Math.random() * [stroypolverh.length + 1]);
var userAnswer = prompt("Построить вверх полутон от " + stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][0] + ". Ответ должен выглядеть так:" + stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][0] + "- второй звук");
if (userAnswer == stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][0] + "-" + stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][1]) {
  alert(«Все верно»);
} else if (userAnswer == stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][0] + "-" + stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][2]) {
  alert(«Все верно»);
} else {
  alert(«Ответ неверный.Подумай хорошенько»);
}
```

Получаю синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: ошибку выдает в строке

Comment: if(userAnswer == stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][0] + "-" + stroypolverh[nstroypolverh][1]){
        alert(«Все верно»);
    }

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Светлана, когда копируете чужой код из MS Word, не забывайте про автоматическое форматирование в этой программе.
Вот как вы думаете, ваши « и » JavaScript понимает? Может, все же заменить на необходимые " и попробовать? Это как минимум, раз уже вы не уточнили, что за "синтаксическую ошибку" вы получаете.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!!!!!!!